# iTextSharp Display only certain DataGridView columns

Tags: c#, datagridview, itext

I want to display only certain DataGridView columns in a PDF file using iTextSharp. I know you can insert the whole GridView into the PDF document. But is it possible to only show certain columns of the DataGridView?

This is my code so far :

```
        iTextSharp.text.Font fontTable = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dataGridView1.Columns.Count);
        table.SpacingBefore = 45f;
        table.TotalWidth = 300;
        table.DefaultCell.Phrase = new Phrase() { Font = fontTable };

        for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
        {
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText, fontTable));

        }

        table.HeaderRows = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
            {
                if (dataGridView1[k, i].Value != null)
                {
                    table.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1[k, i].Value.ToString(),fontTable));
                }
            }
        }



        doc.Add(table);
```

Comment: This question actually isn't an iTextSharp question because iTextSharp has absolutely no idea what `DataGridView` or `GridView`. You mention both above, one is WinForms and one is ASP.Net (if I remember correctly). Regardless, to get from these to iTextSharp you need to have a middle step and its in this middle step that you need to remove columns.

Comment: Maybe you suggesting what the middle step is would help...

Comment: I was assuming that you already had that step done, that you had an existing grid (still not sure which one you are using) and had replicated it in a PDF and _now_ you want to restrict the columns. Since you've said you know you can do this I would assume that you've seen sample code to that effect and implemented it. If that's not the case, your real question is how to get a .Net grid into a PDF.

Comment: Im using SqlCe 3.5 and C#2010. The form is used to produce quotations, and the datagridview lists all of the items the customer is buying. On the form the user enters data into a blank datagridview, which then creates a new table, and inserts all the data into it (to keep all the quotations unique). On the form the user can view all the data, but on the PDF I'd like to limit what columns are being inserted (because the customer will see how much money you're making etc.) is there a way to only show certain columns?

Comment: Yes. Almost everyone uses multiple `for` loops for rows and columns. In the inner `for` loop just do something like `if column == <my column> then skip it` If you don't have the `for` loops part yet see this http://stackoverflow.com/q/13587520/231316

Comment: Thats pretty much the code I use to insert the datagridview into the PDF file. I'm unsure which bits I need to implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have an IDE in front of me so this might not compile perfect but you just need to write some arbitrary conditions in your `for` statements. This code is lifted directly from that page that I linked to, I just added some `if` statements that check the column's name and skip those.

```
foreach (DataGridViewColumn c in GridView.Columns)
{
    if( c.Name == "Something" )
    {
        //Skip this column
        continue;
    }

    //process these columns
    //..
}

for (int i = 0; i < GridView.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < GridView.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
    {
        if( GridView.Columns[j].Name == "Something" )
        {
            //Skip this column
            continue
        }

        //Process these columns
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on your current code and the above you want something like:

```
iTextSharp.text.Font fontTable = FontFactory.GetFont("Arial", 8, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, BaseColor.BLACK);

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dataGridView1.Columns.Count);
table.SpacingBefore = 45f;
table.TotalWidth = 300;
table.DefaultCell.Phrase = new Phrase() { Font = fontTable };

for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; j++)
{
    if(dataGridView1.Columns[j].Name == "Something")
    {
        continue;
    }
    table.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText, fontTable));

}

table.HeaderRows = 1;

for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < dataGridView1.Columns.Count; k++)
    {
        if(dataGridView1.Columns[k].Name == "Something")
        {
            continue;
        }
        if (dataGridView1[k, i].Value != null)
        {
            table.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1[k, i].Value.ToString(),fontTable));
        }
    }
}
doc.Add(table);
```

Instead of `Name` you might need to use `ID` or just the actual indexes of `j` and `k`, that'll really be up to how you've setup your DGV.

You'll also want to change your logic slightly in the inner `for` loop. You are correctly checking for null but you still need to add a cell, otherwise your entire table could shift.

```
if (dataGridView1[k, i].Value != null)
{
    table.AddCell(new Phrase(dataGridView1[k, i].Value.ToString(),fontTable));
}
else
{
    table.AddCell(new Phrase(""));
}
```

One more change you'll need to make is to the instantiation of the actual `PdfPTable`. Instead of:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dataGridView1.Columns.Count);
```

You'll want to do something like:

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(dataGridView1.Columns.Count - 2); //Subtract the number of columns that you are hiding
```

Comment: The code above. `continue` in a `for` loop "skips" that index

Comment: I've tried the code and it doesn't display any of the columns

Comment: @user3521452, I've updated the code above based on your sample posted. Instead of looking at the `Name` value you might need to use something else like `ID` or the actual loop's index value.